# Possible compatibility issues with the subfiles and skak packages

Tags: subfiles, skak

I'm new to subfiles and experiencing problems with the subfiles and skak packages. The following 3 files in a main and a sub directory shows my problem:

```
main.tex 
chess/main.tex
chess/kingsGame.fen
```

I can compile chess/main.tex without problems, but when I compile the outer main.tex with

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main
```

then I get the error:

```
...
./chess/main.tex:4: Emergency stop.
<read 2> 
         
l.4 \loadgame{kingsGame}
                        
./chess/main.tex:4:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
...
```

The files are:
main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chess/main}
\end{document}
```

chess/main.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\loadgame{kingsGame}
\showboard
\end{document}
```

chess/kingsGame.fen:

```
8/8/8/1k6/1r6/8/1R6/K7 w KQkq - 10 10
```

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking? Since this is part of a large collection of files, any suggestions for handling this case will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: \loadgame uses \openin to read the fen and this means that the game is not found. Try with \loadgame{\subfix{kingsGame}} (but this is untested)

Comment: That worked, thanks!